# postgresql:ERROR: negative substring length not allowed

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, substring, string-length

I receive the error message ERROR: negative substring length not allowed when I run the following query in postgresql:

```
update main as m set filcase_type=subquery.filcase from
(SELECT filcase_type ,
Position('SR' in filcase_type) ,substring(filcase_type,1,position('SR' in filcase_type)-1)  as filcase
FROM main) as subquery 
WHERE right(m.filcase_type,2)='SR';
```

Any suggestions for what may have been over-looked? Thanks!

Comment: `position('SR' in m.filcase_type)-1` .. if `SR` doesn't exist in the column the result will be -1 which is the third argument to `substring`.

Comment: SELECT filcase_type ,
Position('SR' in filcase_type) ,substring(filcase_type,1,position('SR' in filcase_type)-1)  
FROM main WHERE right(filcase_type,2)='SR';

Comment: sr exists in all records still the same eroor